# Prolog: Assigning Priority to Atoms

Tags: prolog

I am completely new to swi-prolog but am learning as I go and I am trying to create a program that will choose the optimal option in a certain scenario. I am wondering if there is a way in Prolog to assign precedence to atoms like you can with operators, or perhaps whether I should be using operators to do this.

For example:

```
jeff( studious, personable, cautious).
julia( studious, responsible, risky).
josh( lazy, responsible, cautious).
jordan( lazy, personable, risky).
```

I would now like to be able to find a way to input the following:

- If at school, prioritizes studious by 500 and personable by 150.
- If at work, prioritizes responsible by 500, personable by 400, risky by 5.
- If at party, prioritizes personable by 600, risky by 400, cautious by 5.
- etc...

Is there a way to create a Prolog program that will allow me to type in the location, and Prolog will prioritize the qualified people with a numerical value that changes based on said location?

Comment: Firstly, I'd recommend not using the student name as your data functor. I would do something like, `student(jeff, studious, personable, cautious)` for example. In answer to your question, you just need to define data sets for your information. For example, `location_priority(school, studious, 500).` and `location_priority(school, personable, 150).`, etc. You might need something like `location_priority(school, lazy, 0)` if you do it this way. This is just one way. There are probably many.